# Python - classify a list by the first characters of the numbers

Tags: python

How can I get the first characters in  a `for` using Python ?

Let's say we have  `number = ['078 823 42', '021 932 02']`

`For num in number:` - Get the number with **07** at begining and print it.

**if I use this:**

```
if num[0:2] == '07':
    print(datas.append(num.string))
```

I get this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

I am using python 3.3 and beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to get the first two characters of each string.

```
for num in number:
    print(num[0:2])
```